# Determining recurrence equation of a recursive method

Tags: math, recursion, big-o, recurrence

Given the following **recursive method**:

```
/∗∗ Returns the product of integer elements in given array. ∗/
public static int product(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
    if (high < low)
     return 1;
    if (low == high)
      return arr[low];
    return arr[low] * product(arr, low+1, high-1) * arr[high];
}
```

I determined the recurrence equation: **T(n) = T(n - 2) + c**

and the corresponding base case equation: **T(0) = 1**

To work out the **closed form solution** I do the following:

```
T(n) = T(n - 2) + c
T(n - 2) = T(n - 4) + c
//Substitute T(n - 2)
T(n) = T(n - 4) + 2.c
T(n) = T(n - 2k) + k.c

//Select k = 1/2.n and substitute
T(n) = T(0) + (1/2n).c
T(n) = 1 + (1/2n).c
```

1) Is my *recurrence equation* and *base case* correct and why?

2) Is my *closed form solution* correct and why?

Comment: Note that in some cases `return 1` is performed while in other cases it isn't. Apparently you should have separate cases for even and odd `n`, or involve some kind of "round to even" operator.

Comment: @GoblinAlchemist do you know what the **Big-O** notation (time complexity) is for this method?

Comment: When `n` is infinitely growing, you can disregard `1`. `1/2` and `c` are constant multipliers. Therefore, the asymptotic time complexity is `O(n)`.